# Why does the value printed not change on every iteration?

Tags: javascript

Why does the following javascript log `3` 3 times instead of `0`, `1`, and `2`?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
  setTimeout(function() { 
    console.log(i); 
  }, 42); 
}
```

For each iteration, shouldn't a new function be created based on the value of `i` for that iteration? And then that function is passed as an argument to `setTimeout`?

Comment: Hey buddy, I have updated my answer. Please see it. Thanks to zerkms. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the anonymous functions were referring to the variable i. By the time these anonymous functions are about to execute the value of i is 3 What would be a better solution is something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
  setTimeout(function(i) { 
    console.log(i);
  }, 42, i);  
}
```

Caching the former values of the iteration index inside the scope of the anonymous functions would allow you to print 3 different values.

Comment: This code doesn't work (as intended) in chrome console, for example

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, thanks for pointing out. I have already fixed the problem